# SQL Statement to auto-increment values in column if row exists without primary key

Tags: mysql, insert, case, increment

I have a table with this data

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM prueba;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | U1   | U2   | cant |
+----+------+------+------+
|  2 | U123 | U124 |    2 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

I neeed to increment 'cant' in 1 everytime i execute the statement.
But if the row doesn't exists it has to be created.
The columns U1 and U2 are pairs of data, this means a U1,U2 pair is unique, and thats the condition to search if the record exists.

This is what i have made so far.

```
select U1,U2,cant,
    (
        case when exists (select U1,U2 from prueba where U1='U123'
        and U2='U124')
            then 1
            else 0
        end
    ) as tmp

    from prueba
```

Comment: what about something like `MAX(cant) + 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the accepted answer in [insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql). The idea is to use MySQLs

```
INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```